# How to change selected menu text color or underline - WordPress

Tags: css, wordpress, colors, menu, hover

I've browsed all of the other questions on this topic and tried all of the sample code that was provided, but I still can't seem to get a fix after a few hours, so here I am.

I am trying to change the color of the selected menu page for my site's navigation. I am using the Astra theme, and Elementor Page builder. I went into WP customizer and made my selections for link color and link hover color, but it seems those changes only take effect when I am on the "Shop" page of my menu. The only difference I can see with the "Shop" menu text is it is a custom link, rather than the starter theme default link? Pictures attached to show what I am talking about.

[Red orange color when "Home" is selected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c7huQ.png)

[When "Shop" is selected it takes my selected link color from my global color settings. This is the only one that appears to be doing what I asked of it in the UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dvGbc.png)

[The rest of the menu text does the same thing "Home" does - it draws the red orange color from an unknown source, and I don't know what the color code is or where to find it.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NORFV.png)

I'm trying to either change the selected menu text color away from that red orange color to another custom color -- or keep all of the text as the grey color and make the menu text underlined when hovered over or selected. Issue is I can't seem to make a change consistent when navigating across the menu items. Help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Write a custom CSS property, use this CSS class for your menu.

- Appearance - Customise - Custom CSS (Write your custom CSS here)
- Appearance - Menus - Header/Main Menu
  At the top of the page, you should the "Screen Option" menu... Click on it and enable(check) the CSS class box.

Now, click on your menu items and specify the CSS class to each menu items.

Comment: Hi Michael, thank you so much for your response! I have the CSS option now for the menu, but I’m hoping you can help me determine what code I need to input into Additional CSS + CSS Class to change the hover text color and selected page color. Let me know :)

Comment: /* unvisited link */
.customcss:link {
  color: green;
}

/* visited link */
.customcss:visited {
  color: green;
}

/* mouse over link */
.customcss:hover {
  color: red;
}

/* selected link */
.customcss:active {
  color: yellow;
}

Comment: Paste the above CSS style into your Additional CSS and use the "Customcss" class for your menu.

Comment: Thank you for the continued communication! I input the below into my additional CSS:

/* unvisited link / .customcss:link { color: #4e5051; } / visited link / .customcss:visited { color: #4e5051; } / mouse over link / .customcss:hover { color: #4e5051; } / selected link */ .customcss:active { color: #4e5051!important; }
.customcss:link { color: #4e5051;!important }
.customcss:visited { color: #4e5051;!important }
.customcss:hover { color: #4e5051;!important }

and updated the menu to have "customcss" for each menu item in the CSS classes section, but unfortunately it didn't update?

Comment: Are you using any cache plugin?... Try clearing your website's cache or load in an incognito mode.